# Although I have set the port forwarding for HTTP(port 80), it only works in LAN, not in WAN

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, port-forwarding, nat

I've recently set up an Ubuntu-based server for hosting a website.
I've turned server's IP to static (192.168.1.10) and
set port forwarding as below:

[image]

When I tried to connect on the browser using WiFi, and writing in the address bar the External IP (which is written in admin panel of the router) it worked greatly!

So I tried connecting from my phone (using mobile connection) but obviously it didn't worked.

Using a port forwarding tester, I noticed that external IP is different from the one which admin panel of my router provides to me and port 80 is blocked (but I've turned on in the NAT forwarding).

Comment: Maybe you are behind CGN (Carrier-grade NAT). This prevents you from actually forwarding ports due to a single shared IP address.

Comment: @GiantTree there's a way to bypass CGN? Is this that change my external ip address?

Comment: CGN basically does what your router does: hand out local IP addresses and route incoming traffic to where its destination is. You may be able to get your own IP address from your ISP, but that might require a business contract. Using a VPN with a static IP is possible as well (NordVPN and others offer this service). That way you can have publicly open ports that are routed directly to your servers.

Comment: Contact your ISP about it. Ideally, get your own house-wide IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @GiantTree So there isn't a free way to do this, right?

Comment: IPv6 might work (requires no firewall to be present at the ISP router, the one that does the CGN). Otherwise: Just ask your ISP, maybe they can give you one for free. This won't work over a mobile connection, though.